# How did stuxnet hid it's files after the infection?

Tags: virus, file-system, file-access

I've noticed that when `~WTR4141.tmp` is loaded, it doesn't set `hidden` file attributes to `.lnk` files and on the other `.tmp` rootkit file of the Stuxnet bundle.

I've seen that these are all the possible file attributes on Windows:

```
Let-  Bit   
ter   masks Description and notes
--- ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------
 R      0x1 Read-only
 H      0x2 Hidden
 S      0x4 System
(V)     0x8 Volume label (obsolete in NTFS and must not be set)
 D     0x10 Directory
 A     0x20 Archive
 X     0x40 Device (reserved by system and must not be set)
 N     0x80 Normal (i.e. no other attributes set)
 T    0x100 Temporary
 P    0x200 Sparse file
 L    0x400 Symbolic link / Junction / Mount point / has a reparse point
 C    0x800 Compressed (flag changable with directories only)
 O   0x1000 Offline
 I   0x2000 Not content indexed (displayed as 'N' in Explorer in Windows Vista)
 E   0x4000 Encrypted
(V)  0x8000 Integrity (Windows 8 ReFS only; attribute not displayed in Explorer)
 -  0x10000 Virtual (reserved by system and must not be set)
(X) 0x20000 No scrub (Windows 8 ReFS only; attribute not displayed in Explorer)
```

(Taken from: https://superuser.com/questions/44812/windows-explorers-file-attribute-column-values)

So my question is simple: How does stuxnet hide itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is also simple - inject into Explorer and hook the following functions:

- FindFirstFileW
- FindNextFileW
- FindFirstFileExW
- NtQueryDirectoryFile
- ZwQueryDirectoryFile
  .

[Symantec](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2010-071400-3123-99&tabid=2) has a bit more in depth explanation.

Comment: ah - there we go!